# How to add L1 normalization in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, regularized

I am trying to code logistic regression from scratch. In this code I have, I thought my cost derivative was my regularization, but I've been tasked with adding L1norm regularization. How do you add this in python? Should this be added where I have defined the cost derivative? Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

```
def Sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-z))

def Hypothesis(theta, X):   
    return Sigmoid(X @ theta)

def Cost_Function(X,Y,theta,m):
    hi = Hypothesis(theta, X)
    _y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)
    J = 1/float(m) * np.sum(-_y * np.log(hi) - (1-_y) * np.log(1-hi))
    return J

def Cost_Function_Derivative(X,Y,theta,m,alpha):
    hi = Hypothesis(theta,X)
    _y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)
    J = alpha/float(m) * X.T @ (hi - _y)
    return J

def Gradient_Descent(X,Y,theta,m,alpha):
    new_theta = theta - Cost_Function_Derivative(X,Y,theta,m,alpha)
    return new_theta

def Accuracy(theta):
    correct = 0
    length = len(X_test)
    prediction = (Hypothesis(theta, X_test) > 0.5) 
    _y = Y_test.reshape(-1, 1)
    correct = prediction == _y
    my_accuracy = (np.sum(correct) / length)*100
    print ('LR Accuracy: ', my_accuracy, "%")

def Logistic_Regression(X,Y,alpha,theta,num_iters):
    m = len(Y)
    for x in range(num_iters):
        new_theta = Gradient_Descent(X,Y,theta,m,alpha)
        theta = new_theta
        if x % 100 == 0:
            print #('theta: ', theta)    
            print #('cost: ', Cost_Function(X,Y,theta,m))
    Accuracy(theta)
ep = .012 
initial_theta = np.random.rand(X_train.shape[1],1) * 2 * ep - ep
alpha = 0.5
iterations = 10000
Logistic_Regression(X_train,Y_train,alpha,initial_theta,iterations)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regularization adds a term to the cost function so that there is a compromise between minimize cost and minimizing the model parameters to reduce overfitting. You can control how much compromise you would like by adding a scalar `e` for the regularization term.

So just add the L1 norm of theta to the original cost function:

```
J = J + e * np.sum(abs(theta))
```

Since this term is added to the cost function, then it should be considered when computing the gradient of the cost function.

This is simple since the derivative of the sum is the sum of derivatives. So now just need to figure out what is the derivate of the term `sum(abs(theta))`. Since it is a linear term, then the derivative is constant. It is = 1 if theta >= 0, and -1 if theta < 0 (note there is a mathematical undeterminity at 0, but we don't care about it).

So in the function `Cost_Function_Derivative` we add:

```
J = J + alpha * e * (theta >= 0).astype(float)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this gives me an error that e is not defined. Do I define e in the Logistic_Regression function definition?

Comment: Yes, I should mention that `e` is a parameter which you will need to choose using cross validation.

Comment: I have done cross validation yet, so for this as it is would I need to scale the training data or its error?

Comment: Cross validation is to set best value for e. For starters you can set it to any value (e.g. 0.1) to test the new code... Scaling data should have effect on implementation.